# BigDecimal made Simple - take 2

Tags: java, fixed-point

Following all comments on my original post:

[BigDecimal made simple](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/62436/bigdecimal-made-simple)

The following interface was derived from functionality provided by (mainly) `Bigdecimal` and is now implemented in `SimpleDecimal`.

```
public interface BasicNumericalOperations<T> extends Comparable<T> {
    T abs();
    T add(final T addend);
    T divide(final T divisor);
    T[] divideAndRemainder(final T divisor);
    double doubleValue();
    float floatValue();
    int intValue();
    long longValue();
    T max(final T value);
    T min(final T value);
    T movePointLeft(int n);
    T movePointRight(int n);
    T multiply(T multiplicand);
    T negate();
    T plus();
    T pow(int n);
    int precision();
    T remainder(T divisor);
    int scale();
    T setScale(int newScale);
    int signum();
    T subtract(T subtrahend);
    T stripTrailingZeros();
}
```

And the actual implementation:

```
import java.text.DecimalFormatSymbols;

public class SimpleDecimal extends Number implements
        BasicNumericalOperations<SimpleDecimal> {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4814635367798082279L;

    private final static char decimalSeparator = DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance().getDecimalSeparator();

    public static final SimpleDecimal ZERO = new SimpleDecimal("0");
    public static final SimpleDecimal ONE = new SimpleDecimal("1");
    public static final SimpleDecimal TEN = new SimpleDecimal("10");
    public static final SimpleDecimal HUNDRED = new SimpleDecimal("100");

    private final long value;
    private final int fractionalPrecision;
    private final boolean debug;

    public SimpleDecimal(final double value) {
        this(String.valueOf(value));
    }

    public SimpleDecimal(final float value) {
        this(String.valueOf(value));
    }

    public SimpleDecimal(final int value) {
        this((long) value);
    }

    public SimpleDecimal(final long value) {
        this(value, 0);
    }

    public SimpleDecimal(final long value, final int fractionalPrecision) {
        this(value, fractionalPrecision, false);
    }

    public SimpleDecimal(final long value, final int fractionalPrecision,
            final boolean debug) {
        super();
        this.value = value;
        this.fractionalPrecision = fractionalPrecision;
        this.debug = debug;
    }

    /**
     * Copy constructor
     * 
     * @param SimpleDecimal
     */
    public SimpleDecimal(final SimpleDecimal o) {
        this(o.getValue(), o.getFractionalPrecision(), o.isDebug());
    }

    /**
     * This constructor expects standard representation of numerical value as
     * returned by String.valueOf(...)
     * 
     * @param value
     */
    public SimpleDecimal(final String value) {
        this(getValueFromString(value), getScaleFromString(value));
    }

    private static SimpleDecimal add(final SimpleDecimal augend,
            final SimpleDecimal addend) {
        SimpleDecimal lAugend, lAddend;
        int fp = augend.getFractionalPrecision();
        if (fp < addend.getFractionalPrecision()) {
            fp = addend.getFractionalPrecision();
            lAugend = setScale(augend, fp);
            lAddend = addend;
        } else {
            lAugend = augend;
            lAddend = setScale(addend, fp);
        }
        return new SimpleDecimal(lAugend.getValue() + lAddend.getValue(), fp,
                lAugend.isDebug());
    }

    public static int compare(final SimpleDecimal o1, final SimpleDecimal o2) {
        int result = 0;
        if (o1.getFractionalPrecision() == o2.getFractionalPrecision()) {
            return (int) (o1.getValue() - o2.getValue());
        }
        SimpleDecimal sd1 = simplify(o1);
        SimpleDecimal sd2 = simplify(o2);
        int maxFractionalPrecision = sd1.getFractionalPrecision();
        if (sd2.getFractionalPrecision() > maxFractionalPrecision) {
            maxFractionalPrecision = sd2.getFractionalPrecision();
        }
        sd1 = setScale(sd1, maxFractionalPrecision);
        sd2 = setScale(sd2, maxFractionalPrecision);
        if (sd1.getFractionalPrecision() == sd2.getFractionalPrecision()) {
            return (int) (sd1.getValue() - sd2.getValue());
        }
        return result;
    }

    private static SimpleDecimal divide(final SimpleDecimal dividend,
            final SimpleDecimal divisor) {
        SimpleDecimal lDividend, lDivisor;
        int fp = dividend.getFractionalPrecision();
        if (fp < divisor.getFractionalPrecision()) {
            fp = divisor.getFractionalPrecision();
            lDividend = setScale(dividend, fp + fp);
            lDivisor = divisor;
        } else {
            lDividend = setScale(dividend, fp + fp);
            lDivisor = setScale(divisor, fp);
        }
        return new SimpleDecimal(lDividend.getValue() / lDivisor.getValue(),
                fp, lDividend.isDebug());
    }

    private static int getScaleFromString(final String value) {
        int fps = value.lastIndexOf(decimalSeparator);
        if (fps < 0) {
            fps = 0;
        } else {
            fps = value.length() - fps - 1;
        }
        return fps;
    }

    private static long getValueFromString(final String value) {
        int fps = value.lastIndexOf(decimalSeparator);
        String strValue;
        if (fps > 0) {
            strValue = value.substring(0, fps) + value.substring(fps + 1);
        } else {
            strValue = value.substring(fps + 1);
        }
        return (Long.valueOf(strValue).longValue());
    }

    private static SimpleDecimal max(final SimpleDecimal o1,
            final SimpleDecimal o2) {
        if (o1.compareTo(o2) >= 0) {
            return o1;
        }
        return o2;
    }

    private static SimpleDecimal min(final SimpleDecimal o1,
            final SimpleDecimal o2) {
        if (o1.compareTo(o2) <= 0) {
            return o1;
        }
        return o2;
    }

    private static SimpleDecimal multiply(final SimpleDecimal multiplicand,
            final SimpleDecimal multiplier) {
        return new SimpleDecimal(multiplicand.getValue()
                * multiplier.getValue(), multiplicand.getFractionalPrecision()
                + multiplier.getFractionalPrecision(), multiplicand.isDebug());
    }

    private static SimpleDecimal remainder(final SimpleDecimal dividend,
            final SimpleDecimal divisor) {
        SimpleDecimal lDivisor = setScale(divisor,
                dividend.getFractionalPrecision());
        return new SimpleDecimal(dividend.getValue() % lDivisor.getValue(),
                dividend.getFractionalPrecision(), dividend.isDebug());
    }

    private static SimpleDecimal round(final SimpleDecimal o,
            final int fractionalPrecision) {
        if (o.getFractionalPrecision() <= fractionalPrecision) {
            return o;
        } else {
            return simplify(o, fractionalPrecision, true);
        }
    }

    private static SimpleDecimal setScale(final SimpleDecimal o,
            final int fractionalPrecision) {
        if (o.getFractionalPrecision() == fractionalPrecision) {
            return o;
        }
        if (o.getFractionalPrecision() > fractionalPrecision) {
            return simplify(o, fractionalPrecision);
        }
        return o.incFractionalPrecision(fractionalPrecision
                - o.getFractionalPrecision());
    }

    private static SimpleDecimal simplify(final SimpleDecimal o) {
        return simplify(o, 0);
    }

    private static SimpleDecimal simplify(final SimpleDecimal o,
            final int fractionalPrecision) {
        return simplify(o, fractionalPrecision, false);
    }

    private static SimpleDecimal simplify(final SimpleDecimal o,
            final int fractionalPrecision, final boolean round) {
        long lValue = o.getValue();
        long remainder = lValue % 10;
        if (!round) {
            if (!((o.getFractionalPrecision() > fractionalPrecision) && (remainder == 0))) {
                return o;
            }
        }
        int lFractionalPrecision = o.getFractionalPrecision();
        do {
            lValue /= 10;
            if (remainder >= 5) {
                lValue++;
            }
            remainder = lValue % 10;
            lFractionalPrecision--;
        } while ((lFractionalPrecision > fractionalPrecision)
                && (round || (remainder == 0)));
        return new SimpleDecimal(lValue, lFractionalPrecision, o.isDebug());
    }

    private static SimpleDecimal subtract(final SimpleDecimal minuend,
            final SimpleDecimal subtrahend) {
        SimpleDecimal lMinuend, lSubtrahend;
        int fp = minuend.getFractionalPrecision();
        if (fp < subtrahend.getFractionalPrecision()) {
            fp = subtrahend.getFractionalPrecision();
            lMinuend = setScale(minuend, fp);
            lSubtrahend = subtrahend;
        } else {
            lMinuend = minuend;
            lSubtrahend = setScale(subtrahend, fp);
        }
        return new SimpleDecimal(lMinuend.getValue() - lSubtrahend.getValue(),
                fp, lMinuend.isDebug());
    }

    @Override
    public SimpleDecimal abs() {
        if (this.getValue() >= 0) {
            return this;
        }
        return new SimpleDecimal(-this.getValue(),
                this.getFractionalPrecision(), this.isDebug());
    }

    @Override
    public SimpleDecimal add(final SimpleDecimal addend) {
        return add(this, addend);
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(final SimpleDecimal o) {
        return compare(this, o);
    }

    private String debugToString() {
        return getClass().getSimpleName() + " [" + "value=" + value
                + ", fractionalPrecision=" + fractionalPrecision + "]";
    }

    public SimpleDecimal decFractionalPrecision() {
        int fractionalPrecision = 1;
        return decFractionalPrecision(fractionalPrecision);
    }

    public SimpleDecimal decFractionalPrecision(final int fractionalPrecision) {
        int lFractionalPrecision;
        if (fractionalPrecision > this.fractionalPrecision) {
            lFractionalPrecision = this.fractionalPrecision;
        } else {
            lFractionalPrecision = fractionalPrecision;
        }
        long lvalue = this.value;
        for (int i = 0; i < fractionalPrecision; i++) {
            lvalue /= 10;
        }
        lFractionalPrecision = this.fractionalPrecision - lFractionalPrecision;
        return new SimpleDecimal(lvalue, lFractionalPrecision, this.isDebug());
    }

    @Override
    public SimpleDecimal divide(final SimpleDecimal divisor) {
        return divide(this, divisor);
    }

    @Override
    public SimpleDecimal[] divideAndRemainder(SimpleDecimal divisor) {
        SimpleDecimal[] result = new SimpleDecimal[2];
        result[0] = divide(divisor);
        result[1] = remainder(divisor);
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public double doubleValue() {
        return Double.parseDouble(toString());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(final Object o) {
        if (null == o)
            return false;
        if (!this.getClass().isInstance(o))
            return false;
        SimpleDecimal sd = (SimpleDecimal) o;
        return equals(sd);
    }

    public boolean equals(SimpleDecimal o) {
        boolean result = false;
        if (compareTo(o) == 0) {
            result = true;
        }
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public float floatValue() {
        return (float) doubleValue();
    }

    public int getFractionalPrecision() {
        return fractionalPrecision;
    }

    public long getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        // TODO - Find better way
        return toString().hashCode();
    }

    public SimpleDecimal incFractionalPrecision() {
        int fractionalPrecision = 1;
        return incFractionalPrecision(fractionalPrecision);
    }

    public SimpleDecimal incFractionalPrecision(final int fractionalPrecision) {
        long lvalue = this.value;
        for (int i = 0; i < fractionalPrecision; i++) {
            lvalue *= 10;
        }
        int lfractionalPrecision = this.fractionalPrecision
                + fractionalPrecision;
        return new SimpleDecimal(lvalue, lfractionalPrecision, this.isDebug());
    }

    @Override
    public int intValue() {
        return (int) longValue();
    }

    public boolean isDebug() {
        return debug;
    }

    @Override
    public long longValue() {
        return (long) doubleValue();
    }

    @Override
    public SimpleDecimal max(final SimpleDecimal o2) {
        return max(this, o2);
    }

    @Override
    public SimpleDecimal min(final SimpleDecimal o2) {
        return min(this, o2);
    }

    @Override
    public SimpleDecimal movePointLeft(final int n) {
        return incFractionalPrecision(n);
    }

    @Override
    public SimpleDecimal movePointRight(final int n) {
        return decFractionalPrecision(n);
    }

    @Override
    public SimpleDecimal multiply(final SimpleDecimal multiplicand) {
        return multiply(this, multiplicand);
    }

    @Override
    public SimpleDecimal negate() {
        if (this.getValue() == 0) {
            return this;
        }
        return new SimpleDecimal(-this.getValue(),
                this.getFractionalPrecision(), this.isDebug());
    }

    @Override
    public SimpleDecimal plus() {
        if (this.getValue() >= 0) {
            return this;
        }
        return new SimpleDecimal(-this.getValue(),
                this.getFractionalPrecision(), this.isDebug());
    }

    @Override
    public SimpleDecimal pow(final int power) {
        SimpleDecimal result;
        if (power == 0) {
            return SimpleDecimal.ONE;
        } else if (power == 1) {
            return this;
        } else if (power > 1) {
            result = this.multiply(this);
//          int f = result.getFractionalPrecision();
            for (int i = 2; i < power; i++) {
//              result = result.round(f);
                result = result.multiply(this);
            }
//          result = result.round(f);
        } else { // power < 0
            result = SimpleDecimal.ONE.divide(this.pow(-power));
        }
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public int precision() {
        return String.valueOf(getValue()).length();
    }

    @Override
    public SimpleDecimal remainder(final SimpleDecimal divisor) {
        return remainder(this, divisor);
    }

    public SimpleDecimal round(final int fractionalPrecision) {
        return round(this, fractionalPrecision);
    }

    @Override
    public int scale() {
        return getFractionalPrecision();
    }

    @Override
    public SimpleDecimal setScale(final int fractionalPrecision) {
        return setScale(this, fractionalPrecision);
    }

    @Override
    public int signum() {
        int result;
        if (getValue() > 0) {
            result = 1;
        } else if (getValue() < 0) {
            result = -1;
        } else {
            result = 0;
        }
        return result;
    }

    public SimpleDecimal simplify() {
        return simplify(0);
    }

    public SimpleDecimal simplify(final int fractionalPrecision) {
        return simplify(this, fractionalPrecision);
    }

    private String stdToString() {
        String strValue = String.valueOf(getValue());
        String str;
        if (getFractionalPrecision() > 0) {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = strValue.length(); i < getFractionalPrecision() + 1; i++) {
                sb.append('0');
            }
            sb.append(strValue);
            strValue = sb.toString();

            int dpp = strValue.length() - getFractionalPrecision();
            int p = 0;
            str = ((getValue() >= 0) ? "" : strValue.substring(0, ++p))
                    + ((dpp == p) ? "0" : strValue.substring(p, dpp))
                    + decimalSeparator + strValue.substring(dpp);
        } else {
            str = strValue;
        }
        return str;
    }

    @Override
    public SimpleDecimal stripTrailingZeros() {
        return simplify();
    }

    @Override
    public SimpleDecimal subtract(final SimpleDecimal subtrahend) {
        return subtract(this, subtrahend);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String str;
        if (isDebug()) {
            // Use this for debugging
            str = debugToString();
        } else {
            // Use this for normal output
            str = stdToString();
        }
        return str;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why would a immutable class need a copy constructor?

Comment: Copy constructor is a remnant of my C++ days combined with my original mutable version of this class...
Thanks for pointing it out

Comment: Look at your interface. Is stripTrailingZeros really a BasicNumericalOperation? Is expect a double to be able to handle any BasicNumericalOperation, but it certainly can't strip trailing zeroes. I'm not also convinced that it works in decimal. I think you should just get rid of that function.

Answer (score 1):

I reviewed only a part of it.... it's very ambitious and it needs tons of tests. Get the `BigDecimalTest` from OpenJdk or write your own... and many of them. Run randomized tests for hours and explore manually all corners, if you trust the result. These things are very tricky.

```
public class SimpleDecimal extends Number
```

Make `final` to get real immutability?

I'd avoid all static state like

```
private final static char decimalSeparator = DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance().getDecimalSeparator();
```

It's a pain. An application may start, use this class, and then determine the proper Locale and set the default `DecimalFormatSymbols`. But your class will forever use the old ones.

```
public static final SimpleDecimal ZERO = new SimpleDecimal("0");
```

I'd use the faster constructors here. The class initialization gets done once only, but it runs interpreted and there are usually many classes.

```
public SimpleDecimal(final double value) {
    this(String.valueOf(value));
}
```

Marking arguments `final` makes hardly ever sense. Sometimes, you need it because of anonymous classes, but usually it's just visual clutter. It's not the part of the signature.

I'd also avoid all constructors in favor of factory methods as they're more flexible and descriptive (if needed). A mixture is sometimes useful, too, but not the way `BigInteger` does (`new BigInteger(String)` vs `BigInteger.valueOf(long)`, why?).

```
super();
```

The compiler knows it.

> Copy constructor

Useless for immutable classes.

```
public static int compare(final SimpleDecimal o1, final SimpleDecimal o2) {
```

Why do you provide both `compare` and `compareTo`? Ot did you just forgot to make it private?

```
    final int result = 0;
```

Not needed yet, so I'd move it down.

```
    if (o1.getFractionalPrecision() == o2.getFractionalPrecision()) {
        return (int) (o1.getValue() - o2.getValue());
    }
```

Wrong due to overflow. Even if you needed no cast, still wrong due to overflow. Use `Long.compareTo`.

```
    SimpleDecimal sd1 = simplify(o1);
    SimpleDecimal sd2 = simplify(o2);
    int maxFractionalPrecision = sd1.getFractionalPrecision();
    if (sd2.getFractionalPrecision() > maxFractionalPrecision) {
        maxFractionalPrecision = sd2.getFractionalPrecision();
    }
```

What about `Math.max`?

```
    sd1 = setScale(sd1, maxFractionalPrecision);
    sd2 = setScale(sd2, maxFractionalPrecision);
```

I'm afraid, this can overflow badly.

```
    if (sd1.getFractionalPrecision() == sd2.getFractionalPrecision()) {
        return (int) (sd1.getValue() - sd2.getValue());
    }
    return result;
}
```

Overflow as above.

```
private static SimpleDecimal divide(....)
```

You'll lose a lot of precision. No idea, how bad it can get, but should explore it and document.

```
simplify
```

Three equally named methods don't make it simpler. At least not in this case as you don't document *how* the thing gets simplified.

```
abs
```

... can overflow, too.

```
divideAndRemainder
```

... makes not much sense when doing both operations separately.

```
    boolean result = false;
    if (compareTo(o) == 0) {
        result = true;
    }
    return result;
```

Obfuscated `return compareTo(o) == 0;`.

```
public int hashCode() {
    // TODO - Find better way
    return toString().hashCode();
}
```

Simply `(int)(value ^ (value >>> 32)) + 12345 * fractionalPrecision` should do.

So for now....

Comment: Re: overflow - I wrote this class to replace BigDecimal in my own time sensitive (I was aiming to improve performance and I did that) but value limited (used for money and weight quantities) application. Precision and min/max values were more than adequate for these purposes.
I will review other comments and my code accordingly. Thank you.